# (Radiobutton with JSON) how to check which Radiobutton has been selected

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I would like to sort numbers when I clicked `sort numbers` Radiobutton. I already achieve this by calling a function when the Radiobutton is clicked. however, i couldn't sort numbers without calling a function.
this is my code

```
R1=Radiobutton(root,text="Sort Student Numbers",value=1)
R1.pack(anchor=W)
R2=Radiobutton(root,text="Sort Student Names",value=2)
R2.pack(anchor=W)
with open("student.json", "r"") as f:
        data = json.load(f)
        for d in data["student"]:
            if value == 1:
               data["student"].sort(key = lambda d: d["Numbers"])
            elif value == 2:
                 data["student"].sort(key = lambda d: d["Names"])
            label_1 = Label(frame , text="Name: %s" %(d["Names"]))
            label_1.pack()
            label_2 = Label(frame , text="Student Numbers: %d" %(d["Numbers"]))
            label_2.pack()
```

if I say for example `R1=Radiobutton(root,text="Sort Student Numbers",value=1, command = sorted_numbers(1))` everything works fine but the reason I don't want to use function calling is I would have to create 3 functions to achieve what I want. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to solve this problem is to tie these radio buttons to a shared tkinter variable instance. When a radio button is selected, the value of the variable will be set to the value of the radio button, and then you can use that value in your code.

I haven't had time to test this code, but I have copied your code and modified it in a way that should work. This code assumes that you are importing everything from tkinter, using the line `from tkinter import *`; otherwise, you will need to do something like `from tkinter import IntVar`. There are several types of tkinter variable subclasses (`IntVar`, `BooleanVar`, etc.), and each has the methods `get` and `set`, which behave exactly as you'd expect (as demonstrated below).

```
# This is the variable that will store the value of the currently selected radio button
sort_value = IntVar()

# For each radio button, assign sort_value to the keyword parameter "variable"
R1=Radiobutton(root,text="Sort Student Numbers",variable=sort_value,value=1)
R1.pack(anchor=W)
R2=Radiobutton(root,text="Sort Student Names",variable=sort_value,value=2)
R2.pack(anchor=W)

with open("student.json", "r") as f:
        data = json.load(f)
        for d in data["student"]:
            # sort_value is an IntVar, so sort_value.get returns a Python int
            if sort_value.get() == 1:
               data["student"].sort(key = lambda d: d["Numbers"])
            elif sort_value.get() == 2:
                 data["student"].sort(key = lambda d: d["Names"])
            label_1 = Label(frame , text="Name: %s" %(d["Names"]))
            label_1.pack()
            label_2 = Label(frame , text="Student Numbers: %d" %(d["Numbers"]))
            label_2.pack()
```

**Edit**: Like Nae pointed out in the comments, you can also initialize the variable to a default value like this:

```
sort_value = IntVar(value=1)
```

Otherwise, its default value will be 0. I believe that by setting it to 1, this will also cause the radio button whose value is 1 to be selected by default.

I hope this helps.

Comment: You can also instantiate the variable with a default like `sort_value = IntVar(value=1)` in the same expression.

Comment: No problem; glad I could help!